# SQL Server CLOB data to String Java + Angular

Tags: java, sql-server, angular, spring, spring-boot

I am using SQL Server database and one to of the table has `CLOB` data. I am using Spring Boot + Hibernate framework. When I fetch the data using repository I have getting some encoded string (its stream, i need to convert `CLOB` to `String`), when i use database as SQL server. If I use database as H2 memory database and MySQL then I am getting proper string. So there is something extra I need to configure with SQL server, I am not sure what setting with Hibernate `CLOB` field as `String`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pivotwidgets")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Pivotwidgets implements Serializable {
.....
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "properties", columnDefinition="CLOB")
    private String properties;
.....
}

I have below JPA repository :- 
public interface PivotwidgetsRepository extends JpaRepository<Pivotwidgets, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Pivotwidgets> {

}


@Service
@Transactional
public class PivotwidgetsServiceImpl implements PivotwidgetsService {

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Pivotwidgets findOne(UUID id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Pivotwidgets : {}", id);
        Optional<Pivotwidgets> pivotwidgets = pivotwidgetsRepository.findById(id);

        return pivotwidgets.get();
    }
}
```

When I call above service with Controller, I can see `CLOB` data as stream like :-

Request URL:

http://localhost:9000/api/pivotwidgets/6f6ff3e9-0db2-4525-9e3a-5713d5a0b198

response :-

```
{
  "id" : "6f6ff3e9-0db2-4525-9e3a-5713d5a0b198",
  "properties" : "獡慤摳"
}
```

How can I handle properties filed conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try as follows

```
@Lob
@Type(type="text")
@Column(name = "properties", columnDefinition="CLOB")
private String properties;
```